# How to limit first line in Python docstrings to maximum line length during fill-paragraph in Emacs?

Tags: python, emacs

My setup is Emacs 24.4.1, Linux, Python source code open in a buffer, Python mode 0.24.4 (comes with Emacs), fill-column set to 70, python-fill-docstring-style set to nil.  I call fill-paragraph (M-q) from within a class method docstring to re-format the docstring such that no line is longer than 70 characters.  But the first line of the docstring is always longer.  Looks like the indentation (8 spaces) is not included in the line length calculation.  What can I do to limit the line length to 70?  Should I use python-mode.el instead?

Example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def my_method(self):
        """Some long line with more than 70 characters in the docstring.  Some more text."""
```

After M-q in the docstring it looks like this.  The first method docstring line ends at column 78 (and the second line is not indented, but that's a different issue):

```
class MyClass(object):
    def my_method(self):
        """Some long line with more than 70 characters in the docstring.  Some
more text."""
```

But with a line length of 70 it should be like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def my_method(self):
        """Some long line with more than 70 characters in the
        docstring.  Some more text."""
```

Comment: Same problem with Emacs 24.5.1 and Python mode 0.24.5. There is a bug report: http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20860.

Answer (score 4):

My answer consists of two parts:

1. It is a bug in python.el that ships with Emacs.  See GNU tickets [#20860](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20860) and [#21254](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21254).  The workaround is to format the docstring manually.
2. The first line should be a single sentence that is not longer than the maximum line length, followed by an empty line.  All implemented docstring styles (django, onetwo, pep-257, pep-257-nn, symmetric) follow that rule.  The first sentence doesn't need to be wrapped in that case and the first line can not be too long by definition.

Comment: Do you have a source for (2)?

Comment: @Mateen Ulhaq The mentioned docstring styles are the source. At least that is what I extracted as common part.

Answer (score 1):

With with current trunk of python-mode.el, r1993, and default style `pep-257-nn` it <kbd>M-q</kbd> yields

```
class MyClass(object):
    def my_method(self):
        """Some long line with more than 70 characters in the docstring.

        Some more text.
        """
```

Comment: I installed python-mode.el 6.2.0 from https://launchpad.net/python-mode. With `py-docstring-fill-column` set to 70 it moves the word "docstring" after the empty line.  This it not what I want.

Comment: @holger py-docstring-fill-column is customizable. Having an empty line after first line is consens so far at all styles implemented.

Comment: First I thought I can set `py-docstring-style` to nil (docstring like normal string).  But then I realized that the empty line is inserted in all strings, not just docstrings.  What is the justification for the blank line in any string?  Would it make sense to request a style without additional empty lines?

Comment: @holger Formatting all strings like docstring is a bug, thanks mentioning: https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1476751 For the remaining: feel free to file a feature request just there. Some explanation should be included, where such a uncommon formatting is needed.

Comment: It was easy to add my own docstring stile to python-mode.el.  But I stopped to use it because there was just too much to configure.  After a week Emacs became slow until it was not usable anymore.  With the Python mode that ships with Emacs I can edit for weeks without a slowdown.

Comment: Should you be able to file a related bug-report, that might help.